# i want to show users uploaded pics on log in

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage

I am creating a property listing website through firebase in which the functionality will be in the following way

1 user will signup

2 he/she will fill a form with details of property and then will upload the pic of property

3 **When they will log in again in future they will see their property listing there in there account.**
*Now the problem where i stuck after authentication and database storage of user in formation is that How to let the logged in user show the image and details of property they have uploaded.* 
 thanks in advance.